# Angular Route with encoded query params not being resolved

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-routing, angular10

In my Angular 10 application I have a route like this

```
http://localhost:4200/employee/enrollments?number=189930097&city=Chicago
```

Sometimes the URL is being encoded as

```
http://localhost:4200/employee/enrollments%3Fnumber%3D189930097%26city=Chicago
```

and router fails to find a match. Is there a way to fix this decoding issue and make it resolve always?

**Update:**
I added my footer component in which I am using routerLink that updates the current URL

**EmployeeRoutingModule**:

```
export const enrollmentManagementRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'enrollments',
        component: EnrollmentSearchComponent,
        canActivate: [EmployeeAuthGuardService],
    }
];


@NgModule(
    {
        imports: [
            RouterModule.forChild(enrollmentManagementRoutes)
        ],
        exports: [
            RouterModule
        ]
    })
export class EmployeeRoutingModule
{

}
```

**FooterComponent**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {NavigationEnd, Router} from '@angular/router';
import {environment} from '../../../environments/environment';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-footer',
    templateUrl: './footer.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./footer.component.scss']
})
export class FooterComponent implements OnInit
{
    appVersion: any;
    currentUrl='/';

    constructor(private router: Router)
    {
    }

    ngOnInit()
    {
        this.appVersion = environment.VERSION;

        //Update Need Assistance link URL, this prevents default URL being '/'
        this.router.events.subscribe(data=>
        {
            if(data instanceof NavigationEnd)
            {
                this.currentUrl=data.url+'';
            }
        });
    }

    navigateByUrl()
    {
        this.router.navigateByUrl(this.currentUrl);
    }
}
```

**Footer Component HTML:**

```
<a class=" col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-auto request-help-link" id="request-help-link" rel="noopener noreferrer"
               [routerLink]="currentUrl"  style="font-size: 20px" >
                Need Assistance? Click here
            </a>
```

Comment: You’ll have to find out why it’s getting encoded incorrectly and fix that

Comment: @MikeOne Is there a way in Angular resolves it?

Comment: It is better to fix the code that encodes it incorrectly. 
You can have a matcher defined in the route (which is a custom function that matches the route), but really don't do that. Better fix the incorrect encoding.

Comment: I am not doing anything crazy here, I am updating routerLink='[]' with current URL. See updated code

Comment: Why are you using query strings rather than route parameters?

Answer (score 2):

Would it not make more sense to use a route parameter than a query string?

```
export const enrollmentManagementRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'enrollments:number',
        component: EnrollmentSearchComponent,
        canActivate: [EmployeeAuthGuardService],
    }
];
```

and then route to `http://localhost:4200/employee/enrollments/189930097`

and in your component you can use the ActivatedRoute service to get the param.

https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute

Comment: Actually there are more query parameters, I didn't add them to the question

Comment: Then you should probably use a service to pass the data between components. Query strings are not really the Angular way

Comment: There are cases like this when I specifically need query params. Especially to maintain state when user clicks on back button and forward button

Comment: That is what route params are for

Comment: **Edit: After looking at docs again, I think I can use optional route parameters** In my question I have 2 parameters number and city. If I was supposed to use route params I need create different route for each param like `http://localhost:4200/employee/enrollments/189930097/Chicago` and route can be  `this.router.navigate(['/employee/enrollments', { number: 189930097, city:'Chicago' }]);`.but in my code those params are optional. Meaning not in every request all of these params need to be present

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use something like custom serializer?

`serializer.ts`

```
export class CustomUrlSerializer implements UrlSerializer {
  parse(url: any): UrlTree {
    const dus = new DefaultUrlSerializer();
    return dus.parse(url);
  }

  serialize(tree: UrlTree): any {
    const dus = new DefaultUrlSerializer();
    const path = dus.serialize(tree);
    // use your regex to replace as per your requirement.
    path.replace(/%3F/g, '?');
    path.replace(/%3D/g, '=');
    return path;
  }
}
```

and then in App module

```
...
providers: [
    {provide: UrlSerializer, useClass: CustomUrlSerializer}
  ],
...
```